# MySQL remote connection from outside network

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, networking

I'm trying to let a client on another network remotely connect to a database i;ve setup, but every time I try and setup the connection for them, i get     `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2003] Can't connect to MySQL server on 'servername' (110)`

I have the following:

- MySQL user has been created, with the host set to the IP address of their server
- my.cnf bind address has been set to 0.0.0.0
- mysql service has been restarted
- MySQL is running on port 3306
- 3306/tcp incoming is allowed in the firewall of my server

I have tested it from other servers INSIDE our network, e.g. my own local PC and from another one of our web servers, setting up a MySQL user for those specific hosts, and it works fine. It's just this one outside our network that doesn't work.

Could it be something on their end that is stopping them being able to connect? Or have I missed anything?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To access MySQL from outside. you should enable MySQL remote access .

Here is the way to do so:

1- Comment out following lines in Mysql Config(my.cnf)

```
#bind-address           = 127.0.0.1
#skip-networking
```

2- Save the file and restart Mysql server

3- Update GRANT privilege

By default, mysql username and password you are using is allowed to access mysql-server locally. So need to update privilege.

Run following query to update privilege

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'USERNAME'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Change the 'USERNAME' to your Database user and 'PASSWORD' to User Password

Comment: have you comment outed the bind-address and skip networking? If you do not find skip-networking line, add it and comment out it.

Comment: bind-address was commented out originally, i've tried with it commented out and with it set to 0.0.0.0 and with it set to the actual IP address. skip-networking is commented out. Still no joy.